# virtual machine working and functionality

Tags: opencv, virtual-machine

why we use a Virtual machine for installing software although we can download it in our system also? will I download OpenCV in a virtual machine?

Comment: virtual machine is nice for some properties: You can use a different OS than your host system. Your host system is safe, if you unintentionally install any malware on your virtual machine. And so on. Probably your administrator wants you to install new stuff on the vm to be safe.

Comment: ok,I want to know that how much RAM will i allocate for virtual machine and how can i do that

Comment: what kind of virtual machine software do you use?